# Shell scripting to fetch data from input table:-

Tags: shell

I'm new in shell scripting and would like to get specific details from a table using shell script.

Requirement:-

Input file:

```
model   fuel type   economy
swift    petrol       18
swift    diesel       25
i20      petrol       22
i20      diesel       15
alto     petrol       20
alto     diesel      Null
```

Output file:

```
model   petrol  diesel
swift   18        25
i20     22        15
alto    20       Null
```

I want to achieve this using regular expressions in one liner. Need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NR>1{                                      # Skip first line
         a[$1][$2]=$3                             # Store file content into an array
       } 
       END{                                       # After the file is parsed
         OFS="\t";                                # Set tabulation as output field separator
         print "model","petrol","diesel";
         for(i in a){                             # Go through all array elements
            print i,a[i]["petrol"],a[i]["diesel"] # Print content from the array
         }
      }' file
model   petrol  diesel
alto    20      Null
swift   18      25
i20     22      15
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, however i am trying to get the header automatically form the file, still finding the way using awk command to acheive the values 

echo "Model,`cat file |awk -F, '{print $2}' |grep -v FuelType |sort -nr |uniq |tr '\n' ','`" 

Output :
Model Petrol Diesel

So if any new fuel type is added it will automatically be considered as the header. Challenge for me at the moment is unable to get the logic to put values in column 2 & 3 i.e. petrol and diesel

Comment: What you say was not explicitly asked in your question... Anyway this is not much different from the code above. You can update the code yourself as an exercise. Hint: use a second `for` loop and the `printf` statement (instead of `print`)